# Is there a way to scroll through the skill tree faster?

Tags: fortnite-save-the-world

As I progress through the game and unlock more nodes in the skill tree, I've found that it takes a frustratingly long time to get to the nodes I want to unlock whenever I go to the skill tree, since the starting position is the very first skill you unlock and you have to move from node to node one at a time until you get where you're trying to go. This may not be an issue for PC (not sure if there's some sort of scroll bar?), but it is unbearably slow on PS4.

Is there a way to bypass nodes or scroll through the skill tree faster? It takes a while to get to the far ends of the tree at the moment.

Comment: I feel the same way on PS4, it's awfully slow. The best I could figure out was trying to hold the joystick at a (forwardly) upward or downward diagonal as to skip across and down a few of them. Otherwise there seems to be no way to speed it up. I tried spamming so many buttons to figure it out.

Comment: @n_palum I do the same thing, once you get close to where the skill tree branches, I jump diagonally from skills to go faster. But the first line goes incredibly slow. I would also like to know a faster way if there is one

Comment: I'm not sure there is sadly. I haven't seen the second skill tree yet (almost) so I'm not sure if that is quicker or not. There's no indication of a scroll bar in any version.

Comment: Same on xbox, very tedious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as you pointed out and a few others have in the comments, console scrolling for the skill tree is slow and kind of annoying.

It would appear that there's nothing to do at the moment, other than 1) Submit feedback to the team to encourage an update and 2) Use the joystick on a diagonal to jump around a bit quicker.

There are a [few instances](https://www.reddit.com/r/FORTnITE/comments/6ozq7w/mapskill_tree_controls_on_consoles_are_clumsy/) of people recommending feedback, [especially for a free floating cursor](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/forums/fortnite-discussion/general-discussion/10241-skill-tree-on-ps4) (Destiny style) to make console life easier.

Both of those threads had responses from the dev team saying to submit feedback and or they are working on modifying it.

As of [Patch 1.4](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/news/ea-patch-notes-1-4) they have improved the Skill Tree *visually* making it easier to understand supposedly, but this is not an improvement to its speed.